# Learning Java WebServices

Tags: java, web-services

hi
I want to learn Java web service.please suggest some good books or tutorials for a head start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Two good books on Java Webservices are:*

- **[Java Web Services: Up and Running](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059652112X)**
- **[Java Soa Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596520727)**

Answer (score 0):

I have always liked the [Metro Web services stack](https://metro.dev.java.net/discover/), provided by Glassfish.